# Passing multiple data in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax and I'm trying to pass multiple variables to my PHP file but it's not really working. Basically the problem is that when I pass multiple variables, it stops working. I explain it in detail below.

Here's the snippet of my ajax code. I'm using this to upload a file:

```
var mdata = new FormData();
mdata.append('image_data', $(this)[0].files[0]);
var id = $id //$id is passed inside my function. Just assigning it but not necessary

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP POST
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "includes/ul.php", //Ajax Calls here
    data: mdata, //Form variables
    dataType: 'json',
```

The above code snippet works. As you can see I'm only passing `mdata`.

Now, the problem occurs when I try to pass multiple data. The upload stops working. I tried to send an email of my `$_POST` and I get an empty array. Below is the code that I tried which is not working:

```
data: {mdata: mdata, "prodID":id} //See how I pass multiple variables now
```

Here's my PHP Code. Basically everything works when I pass just `mdata` as shown in the first code snippet. However with the multiple variables it doesn't work(i.e my $_POST) doesn't get the value and even the upload does not work then:

```
<?php
    $fullSize = "../prod/full_size/";
    $thumb = "../prod/thumb/";
    $_thumb = "prod/thumb/";
    $image_height = 520;
    $image_width = 650;
    $id = $_POST["prodID"];

    //gets image size info from a valid image file
    $image_size_info  = getimagesize($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name']); 


    //initiate ImageMagick
    $image = new Imagick($_FILES['image_data']['tmp_name']);

    //Upload Full size
    $image->writeImages($fullSize. $_FILES['image_data']['name'], true);

    //Resize for thumb
    if($image_type=="image/gif") //determine image format
    {
        //if it's GIF file, resize each frame
        $image = $image->coalesceImages(); 
        foreach ($image as $frame) { 
            $frame->resizeImage( $image_height , $image_width , Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, FALSE);
        } 
        $image = $image->deconstructImages(); 
    }else{
        //otherwise just resize
        $image->resizeImage( $image_height , $image_width , Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, FALSE);
    }

    //write image to a file
    $results = $image->writeImages($thumb. $_FILES['image_data']['name'], true);

    //output success response
    if($results){
        $response = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'msg'=>'Success'));
        die($response);
    }


?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you need to pass the `FormData` directly to the `$.ajax` call, not wrapped in an object. You can use the `append()` method of `FormData` to add additional fields to it:

```
var mdata = new FormData();
mdata.append('image_data', $(this)[0].files[0]);
mdata.append('prodID', id); // < data appended here

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP POST
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "includes/ul.php", //Ajax Calls here
    data: mdata, //Form variables
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.